# Accessing objects across domain

Tags: active-directory, domain

lets say i have 2 domains
say  **t1.com and t2.com**

I have a client in t1.com. I need to access objects in t2.com.

for e.g. i need to access an user named **test** in t2.com. At the same time i have an user named **test** in t1.com. how the client knows which user to access? even if we specify like

**t1.com\test

t2.com\test**

where will the client first approach to look out for objects?

Comment: What are you asking? This is very unclear.

Comment: You access "objects" by name, typically beginning with a DNS name. Thus, DNS resolution to the correct object has to happen. There's no other magic.

Comment: Look, no offense, but you've been here 3 days, and asked 5 very basic questions about Active Directory, 3 of which are pretty bad questions on top of being pretty basic.  So... you don't need a Q&A site, you need to read a book on Active Directory.  I'd recommend something with the word "introduction" in the title.

Comment: @HopelessN00b what you have inferred is wrong. what i am asking is when we log in like t1.com/test where will the client approach first? whether will it approach AD in DC or Global catalog in DC?

Comment: I know i am asking simple questions. I know the answer for it. Just to make sure that my understanding was correct i asaked those simple qns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two disparate domains/forests, in order for a client PC to be able to log on to both of them, you would need a cross-forest/domain trust in place.  This would create a "bridge" between the two domains so that resources (including logging onto PCs) in one domain can be accessed by users in another.

There are many types of trusts, and in multiple directions.  You could have a transitive trust, that would automatically have any child domains in your forest trust the cross-forest trusted domains and their child domains.  You can also have a one way or two way trust.  A one way trust would allow resources to only be accessed in one direction, whereas a two way would allow the resources to be accessed in both directions.